# Search for a date in a column that has been collected from an InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to:

- get a date with an InputBox
- search for that date in column K of the 12th tab. (Tab names can change.)
- return the row that date is in

All dates are unique in column K.

I will use that row later to pull data that goes into a summary tab.
(If I 'hard code' the row, the "pulling" part of the code works.)

I get the result of 0 (zero) every time. I know that my test dates are in column K. I'm guessing it's a date formatting issue.

```vb
Dim monthEnd As Date
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim ReturnRow As String

monthEnd = CDate(InputBox("Please enter the month-end date", "MONTH END", "enter date as MM/DD/YY"))

On Error Resume Next
Worksheets(12).Activate
With ActiveSheet
    Set rngFound = .Columns("K").Find(What:=Format(monthEnd, "MM/DD/YY"), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, _
      SearchFormat:=False)
End With
On Error GoTo 0

If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    ReturnRow = 0
Else
    ReturnRow = rngFound.Row
End If
```

Comment: Add a watch and step through code to check the value of monthEnd and make sure it's a date.  It could be because you are looking for a specific format.

Comment: You could do the same with a for loop and loop through each cell in the row

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I just did that and the Type column in the watch window says, "date."

Comment: ah! I got it.  The date formula in tab 12 didn't match my input.  It's all fixed now.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

- Using the `Find` method to search for dates in a range can be tricky, as it may not always locate the cell with the exact date format displayed.
- Optional approach is to use the `Match` function for searching dates.
- It is important to validate user input with `IsDate` before attempting to transform it with `CDate` to avoid potential error 13 issues.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim monthEnd As Date
    Dim ReturnRow As Long
    Dim sInput As String
    Dim matchRow
    sInput = InputBox("Please enter the month-end date", "MONTH END", "enter date as MM/DD/YY")
    If IsDate(sInput) Then
        monthEnd = CDate(sInput)
        matchRow = Application.Match(CLng(monthEnd), Worksheets(12).Columns("K"), 0)
    End If
    If IsError(matchRow) Then
        ReturnRow = 0
    Else
        ReturnRow = matchRow
    End If
    Debug.Print ReturnRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Get Row of Date

**Usage**

```vb
Sub GetMonthEndRowTEST()
    Debug.Print GetMonthEndRow
End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function GetMonthEndRow() As Long
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get Month End Row"
    ' Think about how the worksheet (object) and the following constants
    ' could be arguments of this function.
    Const DATE_COLUMN As String = "K"
    Const DATE_FORMAT As String = "MM\/DD\/YY" ' if '/' is not the default
    Const SHOW_DATE_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE As Boolean = True
    
    ' If the tab name could change, so could the sheet's tab position.
    ' Use the code name instead. Looking in the Project explorer,
    ' it is the name not in parentheses e.g. 'Sheet12(TabName)'.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet12 ' 'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(12)'?!?
    
    ' Retrieve the date by user input.
    
    Dim MonthString As String, MonthEnd As Date, MsgAnswer As Long
    
    Do
        MonthString = InputBox("Please enter the month-end date", _
            PROC_TITLE, "use the """ & Replace(DATE_FORMAT, "\", "") _
            & """ format e.g., today is " & Format(Date, DATE_FORMAT))
    
        MonthEnd = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            MonthEnd = CDate(MonthString)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If CDbl(MonthEnd) = 0 Then
            MsgAnswer = MsgBox("Could not convert """ & MonthString _
                & """ to date. Do you want to try again?", _
                vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, PROC_TITLE)
            If MsgAnswer = vbNo Then Exit Function
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    ' Get the row.
    
    Dim RowIndex As Variant
    
    With ws
        RowIndex = Application.Match(CDbl(MonthEnd), .Columns(DATE_COLUMN), 0)
        If IsError(RowIndex) Then
            If SHOW_DATE_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE Then
                MsgBox "The date """ & Format(MonthEnd, DATE_FORMAT) _
                    & """ was not found!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With

    GetMonthEndRow = RowIndex

End Function
```